# Creation of a MySQL table with a field name that may contain an INT and VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, terminal, phpmyadmin

I am extremely new to MySQL database/table creation.

I am trying to set up a SQL table in MySQL.  I have all of the commands down, thus far.  The one thing I noticed in my data set is that there are certain pieces of data (vendors) that have both integers and varchars in their names.

How can I work around this issue?  I cannot edit the data, as there are certain vendors with names such as M5 and things along those lines.

Also, I am on a Mac, and using phpMyAdmin, if that helps!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use varchar, it allows ascii characters which include 0-9.

Comment: Thank you!

Should I use varchar(255)?

Noob question, I know!

Comment: I mean, it varies, but no way any of the text strings are going to be longer than 60 characters.

Should I cut it off at that?

Comment: Use only as much space as you need. If you know that strings will be no longer than 60 chars, use varchar(60).